# Inclusion of cells within data range, for AVERAGE function, based on criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, statistics, average

I am trying to create mean value using the AVERAGE function in google spreadsheets.
However, i have to program my way out of including/excluding specific cells to include in data range for my function.

My data looks similar to this:

> Q1               Q2
>   City 1              1            4
>   City 2              2            5
>   City 1              3            4

In another sheet i will have to put the mean for the values into a cell, but only for the answers that entail "City 1" so i have to exclude "City 2" from my function. I cannot use the manual data-filtering, as it has to be analysed completely automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want on the other sheet:

`=AVERAGE(FILTER(Sheet1!B:C,Sheet1!A:A="City 1"))`